# replace Scala Case class with Java class

Tags: java, json, scala

I want to parse Json in Scala and I am using Json4s.

```
case class Child(name: String, age: Int, birthdate: Option[java.util.Date])
case class Address(street: String, city: String)
case class Person(name: String, address: Address, children: List[Child])

val json = parse("""{ "name": "joe",
           "address": {
             "street": "Bulevard",
             "city": "Helsinki"
           },
           "children": [
             {
               "name": "Mary",
               "age": 5,
               "birthdate": "2004-09-04T18:06:22Z"
             },
             {
               "name": "Mazy",
               "age": 3
             }
           ]
         }""")

    val must_ = json.extract[Person]
```

This works perfectly fine for me.

Now, I have Java Classes Person, Address, Child in Java too with getters and setters. I want to reuse them instead of defining case classes in Java

How would I do that.

Comment: Use a Java Json-handling package instead of JSON4S? Not sure what your actual question is, really.

Comment: Hi, I would like to be able to reuse Java Classes that I have created for Person, Address and Child. I dont want to create new case classes for these in Scala.

Comment: Then use a java package for reading the Json. A scala package is probably going to use case classes because that is the scala-ish way of doing it. If you want Java-ish use a Java library